# TSQL reading from file into varchar/nvarhar error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, varchar, nvarchar

So I decided for the fun of it to read a text file and store the contents into a `NVARCHAR` using TSQL and the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2.  I found an example for doing this at https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-tsql-of-text-files/

So I tried this with my `ABC.txt` file and its contents are:

---

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>
> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

---

When I first tried to store the contents of this file into`@myString` I used this code:

```
declare @myString nvarchar(max); 

Select @myString  = BulkColumn
from OPENROWSET(Bulk 'C:\Users\<myComputer'sNameHere>\Documents\How2\FilesForTestingStuff\ABC.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) as x 
print @myString;
```

---

> I got this as my output when I printed the string:
>
> 䉁䑃䙅䡇䩉䱋乍偏剑呓噕塗婙਍扡摣晥桧橩汫湭灯牱瑳癵硷穹

---

I changed `nvarchar` to `varchar` and I got the correct contents of the file.

Anyone know why this happend?  I didn't think that there's a conversion difference other than `nvarchar` has more space available than `varchar` and is able to hold unicode characters.
Also how do you normally attempt reading from a file and inserting the contents into a `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it depends on the encoding of the input file.

You used `SINGLEBLOB` and according to MSDN it causes data to be returned as `varbinary(MAX)`. Your file was probably saved using a non-unicode encoding, so when it was imported data into `nvarchar` column, SQL interpreted it incorrectly. Changing the type allowed characters to be read correctly. Please try to encode the file with UTF-16 and try to import data into a nvarchar(MAX) variable.

**Update**

I tried to recreate the issue You described. I've saved a text file with ANSI encoding, run the import script and got the output similar to the one You posted in Your question. Then, I converted the file to ***UCS-2 Little Endian*** encoding and after running the script I got correct output.

To sum it up, if You want to use importing with `SINGLEBLOB` option, just convert the file with data to use ***UCS-2 Little Endian*** encoding and it should work correctly with `nvarchar` SQL type.

Reference links:

- [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foof47eda43-33aa-454d-840a-bb15a031ca17.aspx)
- [nchar and varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok I understand the file reason part, but I do not know how to check the file's encoding and I can't find any TSQL examples of converting files.

Comment: You can use a text editor to check the encoding of a file. You can also save file with appropriate encoding using *SQL Server Management Studio*. Just click a button to create a new script file, enter the data, click on *Save as...*, then click a little arrow next to *Save* button and select *Save with encoding...*. From the *Encoding* list select ***Unicode (1200)*** and save the file.

Comment: @user3003304 - you may find useful : http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html  . To view file's encoding, you can use a hex editor e.g. Visual Studio has one built in, or I like to use : "xvi32".

Comment: So I changed my code to use SINGLE_NCLOB instead of SINBLEBLOB, and I changed the encoding to Unicode CodePage 1200.  That makes it print out correctly with NVARCHAR.  Thanks LukasZ M.

Comment: It should work with `SINGLEBLOB` as well. I'm glad my it helped :).